# Recieving error exceptions after updating Android Studio and Android Studio SDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build-tools, android-sdk-manager

After updating Android Studio and Android Studio SDK from 1.5 to 2.1.2, I am getting error exceptions when I open my projects in Android Studio. Such as:

```
ExceptionInInitializerError: null

NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repositoryv2.targets.SystemImage
```

[following are the issues after gradle building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8oml.png)

When I try and open the Android Studio SDK manager it freezes up  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxZ1w.png)

Comment: I tried to do that same outcome I wven tried to degrade android studio still no use